# Subtrair datas e comparar com valor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, datetime, byte

Tenho duas datas: `DataAcesso` e `DataAtual` do tipo `DateTime`. Tenho mais um campo chamado `TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica` do typo `byte`.

Preciso realizar a subtração dessas datas e comparar o resultado com `TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica`.

A Condição é: Se "datas" for menor que `TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica` "On", caso contrario "Off".

Como faço isso?

Já tentei a primeira parte dessa regra assim:

```
TimeSpan final = Convert.ToDateTime("19/03/2007 12:30").Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime("19/03/2007 12:00"));
```

Mas não chegou no que eu queria.

Como estou fazendo isso no MVC, essa parte evidentemente deve estar em *Controllers*, certo?

Obrigada!

Aos modelos.

## PainelChamada

```
public string Descricao { get; set; }
public bool FlagEstacaoI { get; set; }
public bool FlagEstacaoT { get; set; }
public bool FlagEstacaoD { get; set; }
public byte QtdeChamadasListadas { get; set; }
public byte QtdeChamadasFornecedor { get; set; }
public bool FlagExibirDesenhos { get; set; }
public string UrlChamadaAlerta { get; set; }
public byte TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica { get; set; }
public byte QtdeAcessosSimultaneos { get; set; }
public System.Guid Guid { get; set; }
public bool FlagBloqueioPainel { get; set; }
```

## PainelChamada Log Acesso

```
public int IdEmpresa { get; set; }
public int IdPainelChamada { get; set; }
public long Id { get; set; }
public System.DateTime DataAcesso { get; set;    }
public string Ip { get; set; }
public string CabecalhoHttp { get; set; }
public virtual PainelChamada PAINEL_CHAMADA { get; set; }
```

ON significa: painel está funcionando.

Off:  painel esta desativado.

São duas classes. Observem que vou precisar setar itens de uma e outra pra que esse método funcione.

Comment: Qual a condição a ser atendida? Qual a regra pra variável **TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica** ser "ON" ou "OFF"?

Comment: Se a comparação das datas for menor que TmepoAtualizaçaoAutomatica. Exemplo: Subtraindo as datas eu obtive 5 vou comparar com TempoAtualizaçaoAutomatica da minha Chamada e se for menor será On

Comment: Isso é importante: de que tipo é a variável e que medida você representa no TempoAtualizaçaoAutomatica? Dias, horas, minutos, um `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Mas TempoAtualizaçaoAutomatica não é do tipo byte?

Comment: Exatamente um TimeSpan... O código foi gerado automaticamente e TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica é um byte e pelo caso de uso em si é preciso respeitar isso

Comment: `TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica` representa o que? Dias, horas, minutos, segundos ou alguma outra unidade de tempo?

Comment: Representa Horas

Comment: @ThamiresCunha Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: @ThamiresCunha, não entendi por que seu `TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica` está com o tipo 'byte' preciso saber disso para saber como converter esse byte para um valor (inteiro, double, ou timeSpan) para criar um algoritmo que te atenda.

Answer (score 2):

Ao que tudo indica, sim você deverá colocar no *Controller*. Não garanto porque a pergunta não dá muitos detalhes. Sem você dizer onde vai aplicar isto ou colocar partes relevantes da aplicação fica até difícil responder a parte principal da pergunta. Eu sequer entendo o que significa "on" e "off" no seu caso. Eu diria que é isto que deseja:

```
public bool EstaOn(LogAcesso acesso) => (acesso.DataAtual - acesso.DataAcesso).TotalDays < painel.TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/SubtractAndCompare.cs).

Pode trocar o [`TotalDays`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) por [`Days`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.days?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) se quiser desprezar a parte fracional. Se precisar de outras formas de arredondamento, teria que definir as regras para isto e implementar neste algoritmo.

Comment: Veja se consegue entender com as edições feitas.

Comment: Não ajuda, porque estes dados até dá para inferir o que sejam mas o contexto deles ainda não dá para saber. O que está difícil entender é porque precisa disto, onde precisa disto. Como essas informações estão dispostas na sua aplicação. Dados soltos não ajudam. A minha resposta está "solta", não tem contexto, mas ela está condizente com a pergunta onde tudo está solto, sem contexto. Eu entendi desde o princípio que "on" e "off" indicam se o pianel está ativado ou não, mas o que isto quer dizer no código?

Comment: Bom, não sei se vou conseguir definir direito. Mas isso essa condiçao nada mais é que mostrar no meu Painel de Chamadas se a chamada esta ativa, é tipo uma flag. É uma monitoração que utiliza o LogAcesso e PainelChamada, as duas conversam, esse metodo deve ficar em PainelChamada e analisando bem talvez na propria classe e nao em um Controller. Pois na View que exibe esse status tem como modelo PainelChamada.

Comment: Se você não conseguir definir direito o que deseja, eu não consigo definir uma resposta precisa. O que eu coloquei faz o que parece que você quer. Mas onde colocar isto eu não sei, não tenho contexto. Pelo que está falando acredito que seja no *controller* do Painel de chamadas mas exatamente como, não sei, não tenho informações suficientes. Eu mudei alguma coisa, mas é chute.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi de tudo o que você disse seria algo assim:

```
TimeSpan res = DataAtual - DataAcesso;
if ( (byte)res.TotalHours < TempoAtualizacaoAutomatica )
{
    //on
}
else
{
    //off
}
```